# How to find a field of an object that is a value in a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to check if value of productId is in HashMap, but i dont understand how to adress it properly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Storage, HashSet<Product>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
        Storage storage1 = new Storage("101", "1");
        Storage storage2 = new Storage("102", "2");
        HashSet<Product> myProduct = new HashSet<>();
        Product product = new Product("120", "bread", "15");
        myProduct.add(product);
        myMap.put(storage1, myProduct);
        System.out.println(myMap);
        String in = "120";
        List entry = new ArrayList(myMap.values());
        if (entry.contains(in)) {
            System.out.println("true");
        }
    }
```

Both storage and product classes have private fields, constructors, getters, setters, and hashcode and equals generated by IDEA.

Comment: I would say that you have a data structure design problem.  Maps are meant for rapid lookup of _keys_, to retrieve the values pointed to by those keys.  If you find yourself having to search the values of a map, then maybe map isn't the right data structure.

Comment: Your IDEA isn't configured correctly if it creates raw types like `List entry` or doesn't show a warning if you typed them yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using java 8, you can do this:

```
String in = "120";
boolean contains = myMap
    .values().stream()
    .flatMap(Set::stream)
    .anyMatch(p -> p.getId().equals(in)));
System.out.println("Contains? " + contains);
```

This basically "streams" through the values inside the map, calls stream on the subsets, then returns true when the id of any item matches the provided string, false otherwise

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Using java 8:

```
myMap.forEach((k,v) -> {
for (Product p : v) {
    if (p.getValue().equals(in))
        System.out.println(true);
    }
});
```

EDIT: fixed the answer

Comment: I don't think this has the correct result, `v` is of type `Set<Product>`, but `in` is a `String`, under normal circumstances, `contains` will always return `false`

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped.